# First tab icon not resizing iOS TabbedRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on iOS Tabs using custom TabbedRenderer, In renderer page I am resizing & setting icons. But for the first Tab icon not getting resized rest of all tabs setting icons fine.

```
public class CustomTabRenderer_iOS : TabbedRenderer
{
  public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
   {
      base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

      foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
       {

        item.Image = GetTabIcon(item.Title);                                   
       }
   }

  private UIImage GetTabIcon(string title)
  {
      UITabBarItem item = null;
      switch (title)
      {
        case "Dairy":
        item = new UITabBarItem("Dairy", UIImage.FromFile("dairy"), 0);
        break;
        case "My kid":
        item = new UITabBarItem("My kid",UIImage.FromFile("kid"),0);
        break;
        case "Events":
        item = new UITabBarItem("Events", UIImage.FromFile("events"), 0);

        break;
        case "About":
        item = new UITabBarItem("About", UIImage.FromFile("about"), 0);
        break;
      }
      var img = (item != null) ? UIImage.FromImage(item.SelectedImage.CGImage, item.SelectedImage.CurrentScale, item.SelectedImage.Orientation) : new UIImage();

      var imgR = ResizeImage(img, 20, 20);
      return imgR;
  }

     public UIImage ResizeImage(UIImage sourceImage, float width, float height)
        {
           UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(width, height));
           sourceImage.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height));
           var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
           UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
           return resultImage;
        }
}
```

Below is TabbedPage from PCL project

```
<Shared:MyTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:edTheSIS"    
    x:Class="edTheSIS.ParentDashboard"
    xmlns:Shared="clr-namespace:edTheSIS.Shared;assembly=edTheSIS">
<local:DairyTabPage Icon="dairy" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" ></local:DairyTabPage>
  <local:MykidTab   Icon="kid" ></local:MykidTab>
  <local:Events   Icon="events"></local:Events>
  <local:About  Icon="about"></local:About>
</Shared:MyTabbedPage>
```

See below screenshot

[image]

second screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I think you mean: Diary. Is the image on disk maybe bigger than the others?

Comment: Yes., Exactly. My English little poor.

Comment: Not at all. When I move to other tab first icon becomes small as other icons & current clicked icon(All icons) again becomes big as first.

Comment: Please see newly added screenshot

Comment: I think thats fine. The currently tab's icon is larger to indicate it is the current tab.

Comment: That's fine, still I am curious to know that why happening so. Or this is build it functionality of iOS.

Comment: As I recall you can use different images for the selected and unselected state. You are probably resizing only the unselected state one. Try this: `item = new UITabBarItem("About", UIImage.FromFile("about"), UIImage.FromFile("about"));`

Comment: When I am trying above not getting any difference. When I am not resizing Icons, all icons are showing same size as the first icon showing in screenshots.

Comment: Please show your ResizeImage method

Comment: Please see my updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/), the images should be sizes as shown in the table underneath for a tab bar.

[image: Tab bar image sizes for iOS]

If you size the icons accordingly, they should always show right. There would be no reason to resize in code.

When you still want to use the code to resize an icon, update your `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` method like this, also setting the `SelectedImage` property:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
   base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

    foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
    {
        item.Image = GetTabIcon(item.Title);
        item.SelectedImage = GetTabIcon(item.Title);                                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Great..you made my day. The first point itself is correct that I should use proper sized icons. Second your code inside `foreach` loop is working too.

Comment: I don't know your exact requirements, you might have good reasons to do so. Just pointing out the options :-) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Requirement is common. But I was using available icons irrespective to recommended size & those I wanted to look good :).

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar icon size on **iOS** can be set with the `UITabBarItem.ImageInset` in a custom `TabbedRenderer`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace AppNameSpace.iOS.Renderers
{
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            if (Element is TabbedPage)
                if (TabBar?.Items != null)
                    foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
                        item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(16, 16, 16, 16);
        }
    }
}
```